# Interactive Report Title defaults to 'Applicaiton'

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report that displays Images in one column.  The images are displayed directly from Images I loaded into shared components.

The report query:

```
SELECT
  Tbl_P.ImagePackage,
  Tbl_P.PRICE as PACKAGE_PRICE, 
  Tbl_I.ID,
  Tbl_I.Name,
  Tbl_I.PRICE,
  Tbl_I.Type || Tbl_I.Name as Minifigure,
  Tbl_I.Quote as QUOTE,
  'AddToCart.png' as ADD_TO_CART
from "Tbl_090_ImagePackages" "Tbl_P"
  left outer join "Tbl_091_Images" "Tbl_I"
  on Tbl_P.ID = Tbl_I.Image Package
where Tbl_P.ID = :P201_GROUP
```

The column in question is 'ADD_TO_CART'.
The Column attributes are as follows:

Display Type:  Display as Text(escape special characters)

Link Text:

```
<img src=#APP_IMAGES##ADD_TO_CART# alt=Application Express height=30 width=30
```

Link Attributes:

```
ID=#ID# class="AddToCart"
```

Target:  Page in this Application (Current Page)

The Title is defaulting to 'Application' and I can't get rid of it or change it.  I have tried changing the Link Attributes to:  `title="Testing" ID=#ID# class="AddToCart"`  Unfortunately this has not worked.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are your table names really mixed case? `"Tbl_091_Images"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your link text is malformed? Put your attributes between quotes, single or double. When you view your page source with eg Firefox, you'll notice strings highlighted in red: these are invalid html. The browser is forgiving up to a certain point, but if you confuse it enough things like this may start happening.

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES##ADD_TO_CART#" alt="Application Express" height=30 width=30 />
```

Comment: WOW!  just like that, my issue was solved.  Thank you so much.  when it comes to html, i am just a copy and paste artist.  :/   Thank you again